# Can Sharepoint 2013 be used as a out of box solution for BPM

Tags: sharepoint-2013, business-process-management, nintex-workflow, k2

Can Sharepoint 2013 be used as a out of box solution for BPM.

I am asking this question secifically w.r.t sharepoint 2013 because of the significant improvements in workflow engine and tools in sharepoint 2013.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Sharepoint Out-Of-Box is not a good fit as for BPM Suite. There are key aspects that BPM Suites address associated with Business Process Management as a business practice better than other type of products.

One simple example is that normal BPM Suites use process models that has close compliance related to the official notation of BPM (BPMN 2.0) to display and execute the business process logic. The main point is that good BPMS are oriented to support the BPM life-cycle (Design, Modeling, Execution, Monitoring, Optimization, Reengineering) so this type of products are oriented to give for example monitoring tools Out-Of-Box for business and process owners, and have superior capabilities in versioning and deploying that allows you as a developer to be agile to reengineer your processes and deploy them on Production Environments.

Sharepoint aims to be great solution for Intranet and Enterprise Content Management requirements, and BPM Suites aims to be great for supporting the BPM lifecycle in your organization. What BPM Suites vendors are doing is creating web-parts and specific integrations to Sharepoint in order to allow business users access the BPM Suite functionality inside their SharePoint portal to keep Sharepoint the portal for the end user.

One of the vendors that has this type of offering is Bizagi (Where I work right now), you can read more of their offering on: http://www.bizagi.com/en/bpm-suite/bpm-software/integration/sharepoint

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have been googling on this topic for a couple of days, I too have come to the same conculsion. Currently we checking out K2, Agilepoint and Ninetex for BPM. I will checkout Bizagi too.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start by saying that I know nothing about Sharepoint 2013.  That said, whether or not any product can be considered a BPM platform is a function of your understanding of what BPM is and the functions you need/desire from an abstract BPM system.  If you perform a google search on "What is BPM" you will get back a rich set of reading material on what is considered and not considered to be a BPM system.  Personally, I am in sales of IBM's BPM product and in all my travels, I have not come across any potential customer evaluating Sharepoint as a potential BPM system.  Obviously, that doesn't mean that it couldn't be used as such, but if it were commonly used as such, I would have seen it before now.

What I would suggest is that you make up a list of the capabilities that you would want from your BPM platform and see if Sharepoint is able to address those needs.  If you are looking to make a choice for a BPM environment, then take that same list and compare it to other BPM products on the market and decide whether or not Sharepoint accommodates all you need.

Googling "Sharepoint and BPM" seems to bring out a number of papers that may also assist in your decisions.